Is MySQL access control policy DAC?
I have read in some tutorials that MySQL uses discretionary access control but I have tested that in MySQL the creator of an object is not the owner and does not have any privileges over it. So does it use a MAC policy?
I would like to understand what access control policies MySQL allows you to use with clarifying examples.
